# Convert date like 'Jul 3 215' in a dataframe

Tags: python, date, dataframe

I have a date column in my dataframe that looks like the attached screenshot. I would like to change it to date format like this : `"% d /% m /% Y"`, I tried pd.to_datetime, but this method doesn't work and return this `ValueError : ('Unknown string format:', 'Jul  3 2015 12:00:00:000AM')`

The code I am using:

```
data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'])
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks

[image: Column Date]

Comment: 215 or 2015? Please be more carefull, when you write your questions, so we can understand them more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:%f%p")
```

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE": ['Jul  3 2015 12:00:00:000AM']})
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:%f%p")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 DATE
0 2015-07-03 12:00:00
```

*To convert to your required format* use `.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:%f%p").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         DATE
0  03/07/2015
```

Comment: I have a new ValueError: ':' is a bad directive in format '%b %d %Y %H::M%:%S %p'

Comment: Can you please use `df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:%f%p")` in the previous snippet I have a typo....

Comment: Hello, what should I do if I have multiple columns date to convert to my datframe? Thanks